# Conducting summary statistics on multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, statistics

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere. I am looking to calculate and output summary statistics across multiple dataframes in R.

For context, my data is stored in `.txt` files for each subject - just one column: 63 obs of 1 variable. In total I have 48 files corresponding to 48 subjects.

I read these files into Rstudio and created multiple per-subject dataframes using the following scripts:

```
filenames <- gsub("\\.txt$","", list.files(pattern="\\.txt$"))             

for(i in filenames){
  assign(i, read.delim(paste(i,".txt", sep="")))
  }
```

The nomenclature of the dataframes are e.g. `001_fd, 002_fd ...`

So what I hope to do is create a for loop that calculates summary stats for each dataframe and then output the results for each into a single csv file.

Any assistance here will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is not preferred to have object names that start with numbers. You have also not mentioned what do you mean by summary statistics, what exactly you want to calculate, I'll calculate `mean` and `median` here, you can include more if needed.

First, get all the dataframes in a list using `mget`

```
list_df <- mget(ls(pattern = '\\d+_fd'))
```

Using `lapply`, you can calculate whatever you want. Let's say you have a single column in each dataframe with `x` as a column name, you can do

```
output_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list_df, function(df) 
                     data.frame(mean = mean(df$x), med = median(df$x))))
```

Or with `purrr::map_df` which makes this shorter.

```
output_df <- purrr::map_df(list_df, 
            ~data.frame(mean = mean(.x$x), med = median(.x$x)))
```

Write the results to csv.

```
write.csv(output_df, 'results.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `assign` to create variable for each txt file.

Just use `list.files` all txt files and loop each files to a new empty dataframe.

This is the simplest method but may not be the most efficient way.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.txt")

output = data.frame()
for(f in filenames){
  content = read.delim(f,header = FALSE)
  sum = summary(content[,1])
  output = rbind(output,sum)
}

colnames(output) = c("Min.","1st Qu.","Median","Mean","3rd Qu.","Max.")
write.csv(output,"output.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```